# React props change on setState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

Problem: using setList is updating the component props and the state inside the component, not just the state inside the component.

I have worked out a partial solution, cloning the instance works the first time round, and I stopped using splice, see addPhaseToList function at the bottom.

New problem: After cloning the Phase object the list goes back to how it was in props.

In props it had length 5, ['Phase 1','Phase 2','Phase 3','Phase 4','Phase 5'],
Added something ['Phase 1','Phase 2','Phase 3','Phase 4','Test','Phase 5'],
Added something else ['Phase 1','Phase 2','Phase 3','Phase 4','Test 2','Phase 5'].

Console.log reveals after cloning it goes back to. ['Phase 1','Phase 2','Phase 3','Phase 4','Phase 5']

```
public insertPhase = (phase:string):Phases => {
let clone = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)), this)
console.log('clone a', clone)
this.addPhaseToList(phase,clone)
return clone;

private addPhaseToList = (phase:string,phaseObj:Phases) => {
let result:string[] = [];
for (let i=0;i<phaseObj.phaseList.length;i++) {
    if (i === phaseObj.phaseList.length-1) {
        result = result.concat([phase])
    }
    result = result.concat([phaseObj.phaseList[i]])
}
phaseObj.phaseList = result;
```

Any help would be amazing!

Cheers.

Comment: How did you check that the setList is changing the props?

Comment: If you update the class instance all of it's child will be recalculated and re-rendered. Is that something you want? Besides it seems `list.insertPhase(label)` this is changing the props not the setList method. Try calling `list.insertPhase(label)` without setList in the add() method. And check if the props changes or not.

Comment: “probably where I need to clone or create a new instance.”  Yes.  Do this.  Otherwise you are calling setList with the same phase object instance, but you have modified the instance which you should not do.  Also avoid using splice as it modifies an array.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, 
1. Isn't changing the props without using 'useState' dangerous as the state isn't saved and can be lost when re-rendering?

2. Do you know the best way to clone something? I'm using typescript to it needs to be cloned of the same type.

Comment: You're right it is the list.insertPhase that is changing the props. So I guess cloning is the way forward. Is the way i'm going about this correct? My attempt to use ES6 classes and react?